# Black and white movie about astronauts finding a "too perfect" planet; has a graveyard with their helmets on crosses

Tags: story-identification, movie, hard-sci-fi

The story: six or seven astronauts find a planet where they meet their dead relatives, but everything is too perfect and strange. The next that I remember is that an alien hand touches the shoulder of one of the astronauts, the next is that  instead the "perfect" world on the planet is like Mars, and six or seven graves, and on the crosses there are the helmet of the astronauts.

Maybe 80's movie, as far as I remember it was black and white.

Comment: Are you sure it was a movie? This sounds awfully similar to a Twilight Zone episode IIRC...

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21416/whats-that-1950s-movie-where-astronauts-land-on-mars-but-martians-trick-them-to

Answer (score 19):

"Mars Is Heaven!" by Ray Bradbury (The Martian Chronicles, Third Expedition). It was adapted several times, including as an episode of "Ray Bradbury Theater" (July 20, 1990). [Here it is on Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h6YcI5UzumA), just as you remember, but in color.