# 70s or 80s film. Aliens impersonate humans

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to identify an alien movie from the 70's or 80's in which aliens impersonate humans. At the end theirfeet start to shrink and they start to melt all over, even their faces

Comment: There's very little to go on here. Why not have a look at the checklists on [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) to see what else you can come up with?

Comment: Substitute "Nazis" for "aliens" and this could even describe *the Raiders of the Lost Ark*

Comment: Is this the same as [Astronauts land on planet, met by aliens impersonating their deceased relatives](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/169600/4495)? (The question is about the printed story, but the answer mentions a TV series made from it in the 80s.)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a bit like [They Live](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096256/) (1988), I could be wrong mind you.

Storyline from IMDB:

> Nada, a down-on-his-luck construction worker, discovers a pair of
>   special sunglasses. Wearing them, he is able to see the world as it
>   really is: people being bombarded by media and government with
>   messages like "Stay Asleep", "No Imagination", "Submit to Authority".
>   **Even scarier is that he is able to see that some usually normal-looking people are in fact ugly aliens in charge of the massive
>   campaign to keep humans subdued.**

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! It's usually a good idea to explain what aspects of what the OP said seem to match, to explain why this seems like a good fit, and to mention notable elements of the story that the OP didn't mention, but may recognize.