# Looking for title of sci-fi story/book: About space travel and finding dead relatives on a planet?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this book years ago and from what I remember it was kind of short for a sci-fi book.

It was about a ship landing on a planet and they all found their dead loved ones living there. The so called dead loved ones explain that this place is where they end up after dying and so on. So the crew assumes this is heaven of some sort. They all happily decide to spend the night with their loved ones. 
Only the captain or someone was suspicious of them.

But in the end as far as I remember everyone died. I only remember feeling my blood froze at the ending. It really left a mark. Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: You can read it for free at https://archive.org/stream/Planet_Stories_Canadian_Ed._v03n12_1948-Fall#page/n57/mode/2up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mars is Heaven](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Is_Heaven!), by Ray Bradbury.

Comment: You can find all the details you need [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/169599/astronauts-land-on-planet-met-by-aliens-impersonating-their-deceased-relatives/169600#169600).