# Classic SF short story: alien trap disguised as the astronaut's home town

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

What is the title and the author (Asimov or one of that pantheon) of the classic short ('one idea') tale in which a spaceship crew arrives at what appears to be their home town on Earth. The fatal realisation of one of them ends the story: "he never made it to the door".

Comment: Bonus question: Does anyone remember an illustration where you see the rocketship and two astronauts (one of them a woman) in NASA-style spacesuits with the helmet removed apparently delighted by the sight of everytown USA in the mids of red Mars sands. There is also a sign in the foreground sayin "Bradbury Ave." I think.

Comment: Found it. It's "Martian Chronicle" by Douglas Chaffee (acrylics, 18 x 27 in) ... "produced for the programme book of the 1986 SF Worldcon at Atlanta"

Comment: @DavidTonhofer [This picture?](https://sites.google.com/site/brookscountylit/_/rsrc/1324014447969/home/the-martian-chronicles/Martian-Chronicles-doug%2520chafee500LGjpg.jpg)

Comment: @Henry Yesss~~~

Answer (score 43):

This is "[Mars is Heaven](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58440)" by Ray Bradbury from "The Martian Chronicles". The story proceeds just as the OP recalls. When the captain John Black realizes the truth he:

> ...ran across the room. He screamed. He screamed twice.
>
> He never reached the door.

It's available to read at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Planet_Stories_Canadian_Ed._v03n12_1948-Fall#page/n67/mode/2up).

Comment: Has been asked about several times. If accepted, duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/169599/28516

Comment: Note that the story was re-titled when it was included in *The Martian Chronicles* as ["The Third Expedition".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Martian_Chronicles#April_2000/2031:_The_Third_Expedition)